# How to fix: 'Psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused' when using Postgres in a docker container in gitlab-ci

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab-ci, psql, postgresql-9.6

I’m currently trying to run fossology in Gitlab CI. Fossology requires an external database that can be set up from a schema created using pg_dump. When I'm trying to use psql I get the title error.

At the moment, I have a script that sets up a container that runs the required version of postgres (9.6). It then tries to run an .sql script via psql in the postgres container via `docker exec`. Upon doing so it gets the title error.

I have tried specifying both a port and a host when issuing the psql statement, neither of which worked. I have tried using localhost, 127.0.0.1, the IP address of the postgres container and the name of the container as a host. I have tried rewriting things in different scripts, but nothing seems to work.

After extensive google searching, many people seem to have the same error message but not for the same reasons and not usually when using a docker container to host the database.

When I have run the contents of my script in the command line, i do not get this error, the script works fine and I can connect to Fossology. The issue only arises when trying to do the same in Gitlab CI.

The sequence of steps (i.e. pasted line by line) that works when using the command line on Mac:

```sh
# creates blank database and hosts it in a docker container
docker run -d --name fossdb -p 5432:5432 postgres:9.6
docker cp /fossology_db_schema.sql fossdb:/fossy.sql 
docker exec -it fossdb bash
psql postgres -U postgres

# creates user needed for database to work with fossology
create user fossy with password 'fossy';
create database fossology;
grant all privileges on database fossology to fossy;
\q

# builds the fossology database in the hosted blank database
psql fossology < fossy.sql
psql postgres -U postgres
\connect fossology
exit
```

What I am attempting in GitLab CI:

```sh
# creates container with postgres image
docker run -d --name fossdb -p 5432:5432 --network foss-net postgres:9.6

# creates blank database (error occurs here)
docker exec fossdb psql -h $(docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' fossdb) -f ./createBlank.sql -U postgres

# builds fossology database from schema 
docker exec fossdb psql -h $(docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' fossdb) fossology < ./schema.sql -U postgres
```

createBlank.sql:

```sql
create user fossy with password 'fossy';
create database fossology;
grant all privileges on database fossology to fossy;
```

Expected results: runs createBlank.sql to create a blank database called fossology, then builds fossology database from schema

Actual results: psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "172.19.0.2" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you set up postgres completely?

A few quick checks you can perform:

(Excuse me, you DID do that. goto suggestion 2)

suggestion 1: Did you tell postgres there is a user with a password? (createuser command)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-createuser.html

suggestion 2: Did you tell postgres that user can connect, and how? (tcp or local sockets)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! I'm trying to create a user in the createBlank.sql file as one of the issues is that SQL commands are usually not recognised by the container when running `docker exe` without psql in front. I will update my post with the createBlank file :) Doing as you said produced: `createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?` (I will try using your second suggestion now)

Comment: OK, make sure you know how you connect: TCP/IP or unix domain sockets. I am not a docker-guy, but I expect that will be a different machine, hence a different IP tp connect to. That means you must add a line to pg_hba.conf to make that possible.